# bind a two-dimensional array to a repeater - error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this array:

```
string[,] productData = new string[5,7];
```

I bind it to a repeater and a call a method like:

```
<img src="<%# getPhoto1WithReplace(Container.ItemIndex) %>"
```

which is defined like:

```
public String getPhoto1WithReplace(Object itemIndex)
{
    int intItemIndex = Int32.Parse(itemIndex.ToString());
    if (productData[intItemIndex, 3] != null)
        return this.ResolveUrl(productData[intItemIndex, 3].ToString());
    else return String.Empty;
}
```

I do not understand why it calls getPhoto1WithReplace with itemIndex as 5.
My array has 5 indexes: 0,1,2,3,4, so HOW Container.ItemIndex can be 5...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind data to a list-type control such as a repeater, the only thing that it cares about is whether the object that you provided implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable interface.

If you try iterating over a two-dimensional array in a foreach loop, you'll find that you iterate over each item across both dimensions, not just one dimension.  I haven't tried binding a two-dimensional array to a repeater, but I would imagine that the repeater is stretching out all of the elements of your array into a flat list.

When I work with repeaters I typically work with the DataItem property of the RepeaterItem (the Container) rather than the ItemIndex, as I usually don't care what the index is.  Perhaps that would work for you as well.

You may have to consider revising your data into something more structured than a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a header template for your repeater?

The Items collection is full of [RepeaterItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) - which doesn't necessarily have to be data items.  It can be a header item or a footer item as well.